# How get push notification in real time with quickblox

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, quickblox, cordova-3

I have trouble with the quickblox push notification service:
Some times the push notificatios arrive to my users in real time, some times take a lot of minutes, other time they don't arrive. I've buy the advanced account.
I make subscription and it appear in the quickblox user profile page. I send the push notifications with this code:

> ```
>        var params = {
>                 notification_type: "push", 
>                 environment: "production", 
>                 user: {
>                     ids: recipientID
>                 },
>                 message: "ew0KICAgICJhcHMiIDogew0KICAgICAgICAiYWxlcnQiIDogIllvdSBnb3QgeW91ciBlbWFpbHMuIiwNCiAgICAgICAgImJhZGdlIiA6IDksDQogICAgICAgICJzb3VuZCIgOiAiYmluZ2JvbmcuYWlmZiINCiAgICB9LA0KICAgICJhY21lMSIgOiAiYmFyIiwNCiAgICAiYWNtZTIiIDogNDINCn0=", 
>                 push_type: "apns"
>             };
>             QB.messages.events.create(params, function(err, response){
>                 if (err) {
>                     console.log('push err '+JSON.stringify(err));
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     console.log('push ok '+JSON.stringify(response));
>                 }
>             });
> ```

How can get push notificaions in real time everytime? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the apple documentation:

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that there is new data available.

You should not rely on push notifications for your application logic.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'don't want to deliver data but only notify the user that there is new data available on the chat

Comment: so now i understand that quickblox send automatically and i've canc the code above form my app but now why Some times the alert push notificatios arrive to my users in real time, some times take a lot of minutes, other time they don't arrive?!